# How to enable products for a website magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

How to enable a product for a spicific website in magento 2.

PS in this post you will find a way to get the available website id's:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109292/magento-2-how-to-list-websites-on-frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research a found out that you could load a product with this code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(PRODUCT ID);
```

You can get the available website id's with this function:

```
$product->getWebsiteIds();
```

That function will return an arrat with all the website the product is availble to. and you can simply set the website like this:

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1,2,3));
```

And to save, call this function:

```
$product->save();
```